# Is there a way to copy an array in the JavaScript console with every element being on the same line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console, copy, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a large array of over 100 items to my clipboard through the JavaScript console, which I am able to do, but the problem I am having is that the elements appear on different lines like this:

```
[1,
2,
3,
4,
5, ...];
```

What I want is to copy the array to my clipboard in one line like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5...];
```

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourArray))`

Answer (score 1):

Simply print the string version of your array with `JSON.stringify(array)`